# ElasticSearch how to sort by a giving idList

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sorting, elasticsearch

I have a list of parameters to query, i want to get result sort by this param list order

in MYSQL,  It looks like this

```
select * from tableA
where id in (3, 1, 2)
order by field(id, 3, 1, 2)
```

How to achieve the same effect in es?

```
"query":{
    "bool":{
        "must":{
            {"terms":{ "xId" : #[givenIdList] }}
        }
    }
}
"sort":{how to sort by #[givenIdList]?}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that given the sorted list `[3, 1, 2]` you should return a smaller score for 3, a bigger for 1 and finally the biggest for 2. The easiest function you can consider, is a function from array element to its index. E.g., for 3 you should return 0, for 1 1 and for 2 2.

Concretely, you need a function that may look like this:

```java
def myList = [3, 1, 2];
// Declares a map literal
Map m= [:];

// Generate from [3, 1, 2] the mapping { 3 = 0.0, 1 = 1.0, 2 = 2.0 }
def i = 0;
for (x in myList) {
  m[x] = (double)i++;
}

// Extract the xId from the document
def xId = (int)doc['xId'].value;

// Return the mapped value, e.g., for 3 return 0
return m[xId];
```

Obviously, you can improve the performance, by passing directly the map as parameter to the script as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998273/problems-with-maps-in-elasticsearch-scripts-map-parameters).

In this case the script reduces to:

```
def xId = doc['xId'].value.toString();
return params.m[xId];
```

## FULL EXAMPLE

Index the data

```json
POST _bulk
{"index": { "_index": "test", "_id": 1}}
{"xId": 1}
{"index": { "_index": "test", "_id": 2}}
{"xId": 2}
{"index": { "_index": "test", "_id": 3}}
{"xId": 3}
{"index": { "_index": "test", "_id": 4}}
{"another_field": "hello"}
```

Complete example with the list approach:

```json
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "xId": [3, 1, 2]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
          "list": [3, 1, 2]
        },
        "source": """
Map m= [:];

def i = 0;

for (x in params.list) {
  m[x] = (double)i++;
}

def xId = (int)doc['xId'].value;

m[xId];
"""
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

Complete example with the map approach

```json
GET test/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
          "list": [3, 1, 2],
          "map": {
            "3": 0.0,
            "1": 1.0,
            "2": 2.0
          }
        },
        "source": """

def xId = doc['xId'].value.toString();

params.map[xId];
"""
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "xId": [3, 1, 2]
    }
  }
}
```

### FINAL NOTES

1. The script is simplified by the fact that there is a terms query that guarantees, that only documents with the ids and present in the map are considered. If it is not the case you should deal with the case of missing xId and missing key in map.
2. You should be careful with types. Indeed, when you retrieve a field from a stored document, it is retrieved with the indexed type, e.g, xId is stored as long and is retrieved as long. In the second example the map is from string to double, therefore xId is converted into a string before using it as key in the map.